# In Jira v8.1.3, I want to convert an Epic into a Story; however, I also want to keep the stories and tasks associated with it. Is this possible?

Tags: jira

I want to convert an Epic into a Story. And it looks like I can change  the **Type** field from **Epic** to **Story**. However, this Epic as a few stories and tasks associated with it. If I change the **Type** to story will all of the **Relates to** and **Issues in Epic** links carry over? If not, is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this Atlassian Community answer](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-Software-questions/Can-I-change-issue-type-from-Epic-to-Story/qaq-p/759840) and the [documentation for "Move Issue"](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwareserver/moving-an-issue-939938939.html)  it appears that linked issues will not be affected when the issue type is changed. To ensure there are no problems, it would be prudent to verify the Screen Schemes are the same for your Story and Epic issue types, then create a test Epic with some linked Relates To and Issues in Epic issues and ensure moving the test Epic to the Story type does not have adverse effects.

Comment: Thanks. A Test Epic was my next step to see what would happen since I am not sure and it seems it is dependent on schemes.